# SQL: Find missing hierarchy element links

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child

I have a system which includes a parent-child table of keywords (cols: ID | Keyword | ParentID), a table of events and a table which links keywords to events (cols: EventID | KeywordID).

When a keyword is added to an event, the business logic in the UI will add an entry to the link table for the keyword selected, and any parents that keyword has, so a keyword at the third level of the hierarchy would produce three entries in the link table.

In some cases though, data is imported with only the keywords linked, which could be at any level in the hierarchy defined in the parent-child table. That is, only one record is added to the link table.

Is there a method using only SQL queries (no stored procs) which would allow the unlinked hierarchy elements to be identified and appropriate records inserted into the link table?

Example tables from SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c13c5):

```
CREATE TABLE Keywords
    ([ID] int, [Keyword] varchar(9), [ParentID] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Keywords
    ([ID], [Keyword], [ParentID])
VALUES
    (1, 'Keyword 1', NULL),
    (2, 'Keyword 2', '1'),
    (3, 'Keyword 3', '1'),
    (4, 'Keyword 4', '2'),
    (5, 'Keyword 5', '3')
;




CREATE TABLE Events
    ([ID] int, [Description] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Events
    ([ID], [Description])
VALUES
    (1, 'Foo'),
    (2, 'Bar'),
    (3, 'Foo2'),
    (4, 'Foo3')
;



CREATE TABLE EventKeywordLink
    ([Event ID] int, [Keyword ID] int)
;

INSERT INTO EventKeywordLink
    ([Event ID], [Keyword ID])
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 3)
;
```

Note, event 2 is linked to keywords 2 & 3, but not 1, so the hierarchy is incomplete. I need to identify those records where the parent is unlinked and insert the appropriate records.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to visualize and answer if you had example data and expected output.  A [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) would be an extra bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When data is imported:

1. For each keyword, determine if it exists in the keywords table, if not define it as the parent (ie, parentID = NULL)
2. If the keyword does exist, determine the topmost parent.  This can be done with a recursive CTE.

DROP TABLE temp.dbo.#keywords

```
CREATE TABLE #keywords 
  ( 
     keywordid INT, 
     parentid  INT, 
     keyword   VARCHAR(100) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO #keywords 
VALUES      (1, 
             NULL, 
             'test') 

INSERT INTO #keywords 
VALUES      (2, 
             1, 
             'test_lower') 

INSERT INTO #keywords 
VALUES      (3, 
             1, 
             'test_upper'); 

INSERT INTO #keywords 
VALUES      (4, 
             2, 
             'test_side'); 

go 

WITH c ( parentid) 
     AS (SELECT parentid 
         FROM   #keywords 
         WHERE  keyword = 'test_lower' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT k.parentid 
         FROM   #keywords k 
                JOIN c 
                  ON k.keywordid = c.parentid 
         WHERE  k.keywordid <> k.parentid) 
SELECT parentid 'topmost' 
FROM   c
```

3) Select parent and child keywords and insert into Links table

Comment: I'm not sure this solution will work - the missing hierarchy elements aren't in the keywords table, but in the links table.

Comment: I used a variation on this combined with three nested loops to populate the links table.